# retrieve previous photo taken with camera with ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, camera, ionic-framework, ngcordova

it's my first app with ionic

i'm trying to take a photo in camera tab and retrieve this photo in the filters tab, but I cant, here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane>

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title vcrfont">DSTRY_CAM</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced tabs-icon-top">

  <ion-tab title="WTF?" icon-on="ion-ios-help" icon-off="ion-ios-help-outline">
    <ion-pane>
      <div id="welcome">
        <h2>WELCOME TO<br>DSTRY_CAM</h2>

        <h3>INSTRUCTIONS:</h3>
        <h3>1.SHOOT</h3>
        <h3>2.DESTROY</h3>
        <h3>3.SHARE</h3>

      </div>



    </ion-pane>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Camera" icon-on="ion-ios-camera" icon-off="ion-ios-camera-outline">
  <ion-pane ng-controller="ExampleController" class="centrar">
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
    </ion-pane>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Filters" icon-on="ion-ios-flask" icon-off="ion-ios-flask-outline">
    <ion-pane ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
      <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </ion-pane>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Share" icon-on="ion-ios-upload" icon-off="ion-ios-upload-outline">
    <ion-pane>
    <button class="button button-light shurmargen"> 
     heheh
    </button>
    </ion-pane>
  </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-pane>
```

and the .js

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }

});
```

the camera works well, but the photo only shows in camera tab, and i need to show it in filters and share tabs too

thanks!

Comment: ok, i used $rootScope instead of $scope and seems to work.

is that the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        });            
    }, function(err) {
        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
```

you have to use $scope.apply to apply the changes in your $scope variable.